Removing Null Fields from an Object in Java Without Affecting Global ObjectMapper Configuration
I have a Person class with firstName, lastName, and email fields, and I'm using this class in multiple places. In one specific method, I want to remove null fields from the Person object.
Conditions:

We're using a singleton ObjectMapper, and we can't globally configure it to exclude null fields since it's used across various parts of the application.
We cannot apply annotations to the class, as it's provided in a different jar.

Currently, we're using the Reflection API, but we're looking for a simpler and better solution.
Example:
Original person:
Person{firstName='John', lastName='', email=null}
Filtered person:
Person{firstName='John'}

Why not create a new instance of the ObjectMapper for this specific case something like emptyFieldIgnoringObjectMapper?

"We can apply annotations" you mean "can't"?

We cannot apply annotations to the class, as it's provided in a different jar. - you can actually do that. Check mixins in object mapper. Javadoc - ObjectMapper.addMixin().

You can create a copy with
objectMapper.copy().setDefaultPropertyInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)


Yes, we can do that, but I don't want to create a copy of the ObjectMapper. What's a more proper solution?

You can't pass configuration to writeValueAsString or similar. So there is no more proper solution. Actually there is no other solution AFAIK.

If I understand your problem, you have two options.
You can use the annotation from com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation to remove null fields. For example, add the annotation @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL) to your object.
Example:
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class TestDto {

    @JsonProperty("name")
    private String name;
    @JsonProperty("email")
    private String email;
}

Alternatively, you can configure your global mapper with:
mapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL);

Be careful with the version of com.fasterxml.jackson you are using. If you are using a version below 2.x, the annotation is:
@JsonSerialize(include = JsonSerialize.Inclusion.NON_NULL)


Both your solutions violate the conditions in the question: 1. We're using a singleton ObjectMapper, and we can't globally configure it to exclude null fields, 2. We cannot apply annotations to the class.

I just noticed now that you cannot use annotations. In that case, you can try using a separate ObjectMapper to remove null fields. You would have two mappers: a standard one and another configured to ignore null fields.
